# Why is this cppreference demo program causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reviewing a variant of the [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) function by testing it on my compiler. For some reason this program fails in both latest clang++ and g++4.8. In my opinion this looks like a correct program that *should* work.

> `g++-4.8 -std=c++1y -O3 -Wall -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`
>
> terminate called without an active exception
> `/tmp/1370796977-600590525/cmd.sh: line 7: 22819 Aborted (core dumped) ./a.out`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void f(int n)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(n));
    std::cout << "thread " << n << " ended" << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.emplace_back(f, 1);
    v.emplace_back(f, 2);
    v.emplace_back(f, 3);
    std::list<std::thread> l;

    for(auto& t : l) t.join();
}
```

I notice that the part that causes the error is the `emplace_back` lines. When I remove them the program compiles normally. Why is this happening and why is it failing on all compilers I've tried thus far?

Comment: Why do you declare `std::list<std::thread> l` but never assign anything to it before trying to loop over it? It looks like you have some code missing.

Comment: That's not the code you've linked to, you're missing the important `std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(l));`

Comment: @nos Yeah I don't know how I didn't get that...

Comment: Also, the `(core dumped)` implies that you've got a runtime error, but "compiles normally" implies that you've got a compile time error. Which is it?

Comment: @0x499602D2 When you copy-paste (at least in Firefox), the line `std::move(..)` gets stuck in the comment above the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not joining the threads in `main()`. You need

```
 for(auto& t : v) t.join();
 //            ^ Look, v not l
```

Alternatively, place this line before your original loop to move the threads from the `v` into `l`:

```
std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(l)); 
for(auto& t : l) t.join();
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to leave the list empty, and exit main with unjoined threads in v.

IIRC destructor of `std::thread` calls terminate if not joined.

Answer (score 1):

you try iterate over empty `l`, but `'join` is not accomplished for real threads